# kafka custom partitioner with pyspark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I want to use kafka custom partitioner for my pyspark application reading from kafka pushing to another kafka topic. Data is transformed from source to sink with pyspark processing. I want to have control over partition to which data should be pushed based on some key in data/message. In [spark structured streaming documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) I couldn't find any reference or example for such use case. I am using python processing along with pyspark and [confluent-kafka-python](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) is used as kafka client there, but it also lacks documentation/example for custom partitioner.

is solution available to achieve this?

Below spark code is tried with partition column and is not pushing data as per partition column.

```
df = spark.range(5)
df = (df
      .withColumn("topic", F.lit("test_temp"))
      .withColumn("partition", (F.col("id")%2).cast("int"))
      .withColumn("key", F.lit("test"))
      .withColumn("value", F.lit("test_data"))
    ).select(["topic", "key", "value", "partition"])

df.printSchema()

(df.write.format("kafka").partitionBy("partition")
 .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_endpoint)
 #.option("topic", "test_temp")
 .save())
```

Output:

```
+---------+----+---------+---------+
|    topic| key|    value|partition|
+---------+----+---------+---------+
|test_temp|test|test_data|        0|
|test_temp|test|test_data|        1|
|test_temp|test|test_data|        0|
|test_temp|test|test_data|        1|
|test_temp|test|test_data|        0|
+---------+----+---------+---------+

root
 |-- topic: string (nullable = false)
 |-- key: string (nullable = false)
 |-- value: string (nullable = false)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
```

Kafka console consumer output:

```
 ./kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server <broker>:9092 --topic test_temp --partition 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [Structured Streaming documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-data-to-kafka), you'd either add a column to the dataframe being written called `partition` of an int type, and this controls which partition that Spark will write to. Or you can add a JVM paritioner to the classpath.

> If a “partition” column is not specified (or its value is null) then the partition is calculated by the Kafka producer. A Kafka partitioner can be specified in Spark by setting the kafka.partitioner.class option. If not present, Kafka default partitioner will be used.

Regarding the Confluent Python client - https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/1107

But `kafka-python` module does support custom partitioners

Comment: adding a partition column of type int doesn't work.  Attaching code snippet for it in actual question.

Comment: Are you running the console consumer before Spark writes data? If not, you need to add `--from-beginning`. Also, I don't think you need to partition the dataframe